# race condition between wait_event and wake_up

Tags: linux-kernel, ipc, linux-device-driver, race-condition

I have a driver that wants to send notification to the user about a status change. In the current implementation it uses the proc filesystem to do so. The read process loops around a `read()` to the proc filesystem. The `read()` blocks with `wait_event_interruptible()` until the kernel gets an interrupt which causes the `write_new_data()` function to `call wake_up_interruptible()`. Here's the basic code (removed all unneeded clutter):

```
static int flag=0;
DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(info_wq);

//user process call read() on /proc/myfile to get to this function
int my_proc_read (struct file *filp, char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *pos)
{
    wait_event_interruptible(info_wq, flag != 0);
    flag = 0;

    //copy buffers to user
    return 0;
}


//when an interrupt comes it schedules this function on the systems' work queue
void write_new_data ()
{
    //fill buffer with data
    flag = 1;
    wake_up_interruptible(&info_wq);
}
```

Now consider the following flow:

1. User process calls `read()`, then waits.
2. interrupt occurs -> `write_new_data()` is called. writes data and calls `wake_up_interruptible()`.
3. `read()` is awaken, reads data but process has not rerun read (wasn't scheduled
   to run, didn't get to it because of the next interrupt...).
4. interrupt occurs -> `write_new_data()` is triggered again, calls `wake_up_interruptible()` but no waiting thread is waiting...
5. process calls read and blocks.

Note: this all happens on a uni-processor system. Also there is only one thread reading and one thread writing new data.

How can I avoid missing the second interrupt? (One solution is to use netlink sockets but I was wondering if there is a way to do it in /proc land)

Comment: what kind of driver is it? and what status it is chacking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the interrupt can occur between the call to `wait_event_interruptible` and `flag = 0`, it would affect the `flag` variable in an unwanted way.

Note that even on a UP machine, the kernel could be preemptive depending on the configuration, and that code would be affected as a result.

Also, I advice to not use a simple 'int' flag. Instead, you should use `atomic_t` and `atomic_dec/inc_*` operations. See the implementation of completions inside the kernel, it does something similar to what you are doing here.

About the question itself:

If you'll look in the code of `wait_event_interruptible` you'll see that the sleep doesn't take place if the condition is true - so your problem is a non-problem.

Comment: Well, for simplicity I took out the code part with spin locks that controls the changing of the flag. Thanks for tips on atomic_dec/inc and completions - I'll read more about those. Still my basic question remains unanswered...

Comment: There's something not quite right with the flow you are presenting. After the second interrupt, flag == 1, and the next call to `read`, even if it got delayed by the interrupt, cannot seem to block because `wait_Event_interruptible` would exit immediately because of the provided condition.

Comment: Here we disagree. My understanding is that if when the wake is called no thread is on the wait queue (not called wait_event) then the fact that the condition is true won't help and the process will sleep until someone calls wake_up again (and only then will the condition be checked for true)

Comment: No, that is not how this works. Just look at the definition of the `__wait_event_interruptible` macro. It returns if the condition is met **before** calling schedule(), therefore it wouldn't sleep if the condition is already met.

Comment: from the code - it looks you're very right and Im very wrong...I'll test code it with a simple module and report back

Answer (score 4):

Dan, here is the  code of wait_event_interruptible :

```
#define wait_event_interruptible(wq, condition)             \
({                                  \
    int __ret = 0;                          \
    if (!(condition))                       \
        __wait_event_interruptible(wq, condition, __ret);   \
    __ret;                              \
})
```

If an interrupt occurs just between "if (!(condition))" and "__wait_event_interruptible", the sleep will take place and the read process will be block untill another interrupt occurs.

Comment: no, look at __wait_event_interrupts() - it does `if (condition) break` before sleeping.

Comment: typo ; I meant look at __wait_event_interruptible(). It checks the condition again. To elucidate even further - even if the interrupt happened after the second check, the call to schedule() will return immediately because of the call to wake_up in the interrupt. The reason that __wait_event_interruptible calls prepare_to_wait() *before* checking the condition again is to prevent races on the update of the condition. Thus, the APIs are valid, but the handling of `flag` in the question is still a bug.

Comment: I found this: [link](http://www.mail-archive.com/kernelnewbies@nl.linux.org/msg04972.html)
__wait_event_interruptible():
<code>
prepare_to_wait(&wq, &__wait, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
if (condition)
break;
if (!signal_pending(current))
ret = schedule_timeout(ret);
</code>
If the condition and a wake_up() occur just before the call to prepare_to_wait() and if this code is preempted just after the call to prepare_to_wait(), in that case it would not be run again by the scheduler since it is in the TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE state.